# Localizing dynamic NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

Going through number of examples regarding to NSLocalizedString, what I found was we need to pre-define all the string in Localized.string file  for what-ever language you want to localize. But, is it possible to localize dynamic string. My idea was,  I am displaying few text in UILabel that i get after web request. It means the string is now dynamic in nature.

Comment: have you trying google it for language translating private api..?

Answer (score 2):

Declare in  Localizable.strings

```
"SAMPLE_LOCALIZE_STRING" = "This is sample dynamic localize string for %@.";
```

Use it like this

```
NSString *dynamicStr = @"Test";
label.Text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"SAMPLE_LOCALIZE_STRING", nil), dynamicStr];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Table View Cell Row %d", @""), indexpath.row];
```

Comment: I usually save the string after I get it. So the thing is i need to do  it in offline mode (locally).

Comment: You can add Localized String in above showed format in offline, & it will dynamically effects once we get the data.

Answer (score 1):

If those strings are fixed ones (I mean a limited number of options) then pre-store them in the localized string file.

If not, I would suggest to add a parameter to your request that would indicate the language and then the server would return string in that language.

Comment: I usually save the string after I get it. So the thing is i need to do it in offline mode (locally).

Comment: Even if you store it once you receive it won't matter. Either it should be in plist in order to get localized string automatically. Else you would need to get localized string from server, since even if you save the string, its somewhere else and not in the localized string file.

Answer (score 1):

I have handled this situation as follows,

Include language in the request. For ex: `http://yourIp/language/notesandcondition`

The webservice should be designed to handle for different languages.